# How to sync with data from oracle to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, input, plugins

I need to  sync my oracle data with elastic search , when i search on net i found 3 ways it can be done

1. Using Logstash JDBC input plugin
2. Using Kafka connect JDBC
3. Using Elasticsearch JDBC input plugin

I am using `jdk1.8` and `elsaticsearch 7.2`.

I want to use through JDBC input plugin i search for installer and steps to configure , not able to found .

Can you please guide me on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone for the Logstash JDBC input plugin plugin. Should be pretty straight forward and the continuous syncing is [well documented](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-keep-elasticsearch-synchronized-with-a-relational-database-using-logstash).

PS: "Elasticsearch JDBC input plugin" are you sure there is such a thing? Generally you don't want to do any blocking (especially IO) calls in Elasticsearch — that's why Rivers were removed and we're careful not to add any such problems again.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I am not sure there is elastic search jdbc plugin, i come across this option when i search in net.